# Finding the image of an arbitrary vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not exactly sure how to find the image of an arbitrary vector

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and form a basis. So you only need to write an arbitrary vector as linear combination of them.

Let
$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$
or
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3x-2y\\-x+y \end{bmatrix}$$
So
$$T\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}=T\left( (3x-2y)v_1+(-x+y)v_2\right)$$
$$=(3x-2y)T(v_1)+(-x+y)T(v_2)$$
$$=(3x-2y)\begin{bmatrix}-11\\4\end{bmatrix}+(-x+y)\begin{bmatrix}-28\\13\end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}-5x-6y\\-x+5y\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right) $ and $e_2=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1
\end{array}
\right) $ then $T\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) =xT(e_1)+yT(e_2)$ or $v_1=e_1+e_2$ and $v_2=2e_1+3e_2$ so
$e_1=3v_1-v_2$ and $e_2=v_2-2v-1$, then $T\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) = = (3x-2y)T(v_1)+(y-x)T(v_2)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5x-6y \\
-x+5y
\end{array}
\right)$